# Argue that $\gamma_0$ cannot be a maximum of the action

Tags: geometry, analysis, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

We consider once more the one-dimensional harmonic oscillator with the Lagrangian given by:
$$L(x,v)=\frac{m}{2}v^2-\frac{k}{2}x^2,k>0$$
and the corresponding action on trajectories $\gamma$ given by the functional:
$$S(\gamma)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}L(\gamma(t),\dot{\gamma(t)})dt.$$

I have found the Euler-Lagrange equation of the system to:
$$-kx=m \ddot{x}$$
And the solution to:
$$x(t) = c_1 \cos(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t ) + c_2 \sin(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t)$$
We assume that $\gamma_0(t)$  solution of the Euler-Lagrange-equation satisfying $\gamma_0(t_1 = 0) = \xi$ and $\gamma_0(t_2 = T) = \eta$.  And variation of the trajectory $\gamma_0$ given as $\gamma(t) = \gamma_0(t) + \nu(t)$ with $\nu$ some
curve satisfying $\nu(0) = \nu(T) = 0$. We have that $S(\gamma)$
and $S(\gamma_0)$ is given by:
$$\Delta S=S(\gamma)-S(\gamma_0)=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^T m \dot \nu^2(t)-k\nu^2(t)dt$$
We have to use this to argue that that $\gamma_0$ cannot be a maximum of the action. Can anyone help me what that argue could be? I'm a bit lost

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/685853/2451

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Consider the sequence
   $$ \nu_n(t)~:=~A \sin\left( \frac{n\pi t}{T}\right) ,\qquad n~\in~\mathbb{N}, \qquad A~>~0. $$
2. Show that
   $$\Delta S~=~S[\gamma_0+\nu_n]-S[\gamma_0]~=~S[\nu_n]~\to~ \infty\quad {\rm for}\quad n~\to~\infty. $$
3. To develop a more systematic understanding of the problem, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/682652/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: So then $\gamma_0$ can not be a minimum either? And how can I use this velocity  sequence to find conditions so I can get negative values for $\Delta S$? Can you help me?

Comment: I have made a new question with me thoughts https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346346/argue-for-formula-about-one-dimensional-harmonic-oscillator

Comment: I'm still confused here. $sin(x)$ for $x-> \infty$ is not defined? So how can this argument be used?

Comment: $\nu_n$ does not converge; only $S[\nu_n]$ converges.